# How to create costum column widget in a CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I want to create a celltable which column can have costumn widgets like rating.

After researches, i find that i have to create a class that extends AbstractCell, But it isn't very clear.

Can somebody help me, or is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Maybe this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548420/custom-gxt-cell-which-may-take-widget) will help you.

Comment: Or start with the GoogleDoc: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html and continue with an example like this: http://programmingfortherestofus.blogspot.ro/2012/04/gwt-custom-celltable-column.html or even the GWT showcase