# Using two nested CellLists

Tags: gwt, uibinder, celllist

I'm trying to use two nested Cell-Lists while using the GWT UI-Binder for both of these lists. 
Basically, I have a model-list, and every model-element contains an article-list as an UI-field. Unfortunately, a model-element (which is an AbstractCell-class) can't bind another CellList as an UI-field because AbstractCell is not a Widget. The only solution I found is passing the article-list as an HTML-string in the render-method of the AbstractCell-class.

So my question is whether there is any possibility to use a CellList (article-list) as an UI-field in another CellList (model-list) while using the UI-Binder for both of these lists?

Comment: ui-binder is something you use for Composite subclasses. Why do you want the nested cell to be a @UiField? You can store it as a field of your Top-level CellList, right?

Comment: every cell of my model-list (Top-level CellList) should have an own article-list ( represented by an UI-Binder). So I have several article-lists (one for every model-element).

Comment: if those are going be used for editing - perhaps you need just one, as a popup? Otherwise - you can put a widget there like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548420/custom-gxt-cell-which-may-take-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CellList`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?overview-summary.html) is a very flat `Widget` type. Basically you are just rendering cells by returning HTML.
Therefore you will not be able to easily nest another `Widget` into a `CellList`.

I would also think that your UI might be complicated for the user if there is another list inside your main list - if I did not get you wrong on that?

Usually I would solve that by providing two lists - either one over the other or side-by-side. The first list is the main or master list and the second one is the child list. If you select an item in the master list, you populate the child list with all according child entries. And if you put a label "model" and "article" on them, it should be pretty clear to the user. Just keep the master list first in your UI first - at least if your UI is targeted to left-to-right (RTL) reading people.